# Trim Whitespace in a string

Tags: php, trim, removing-whitespace

**PHP:**
I want to `trim()` the whitespace off the beginning of a string using php, but the default settings in `trim()` aren't handling the the whitespace characters. The white space is 7 spaces long. Is there a way to remove the 7 spaces using `trim()` or another function?

A function that trims everything until a "normal" character (quotes as in I don't know what to call a normal character) is encountered would work.

Comment: I would post the whitespace here, but I really have no idea how to show it.

Comment: Something like `for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) { print_r(ord($str[$i]));}` should at least identify what the characters actually are.

Comment: well, for a start, you could convert the strint to an array of bytes and post the ascii values of the bytes here. But alternatively, if you did not magically manage to find a new whitespace character, it would be of more help to post your code here.

Comment: @lonesomeday - 160 is the value of the white space in from your function.

Comment: well, that's odd. but it's not whitespace. :)

Comment: Oh, that's ascii so it's &nbsp; ... Should have known.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ltrim()` method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Comment: regarding the problem he stated, I doubt that this will solve his problems.

Answer (score 1):

the php function trim() does, following its specification, remove all whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string, where whitespace includes space, tab, newlines and zero byte. I guess you must be using it incorrectly then? Some code would definitley help solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of all sorts of evil whitespaces (there is more than just the ASCII variants) you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\pZ+/u', '', $str);
```

If that doesn't work then you'll have to look into the actual characters first. Use [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/bin2hex%28%29) or an hexeditor of your choosing to inspect what you actually have in your string.

Answer (score 0):

trim() handles the following whitespace characters, by default:

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

this would imply that your whitespace is not one of these. If you can figure out what kind of whitespace it is, you can supply it as an argument to trim()

Comment: Agreed, any idea how to identify it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need:

```
function remWhite($str) {
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$str);
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: a regex for a trim job? are you serious? O_o That's 1.) utterly inefficient and 2.) showing different behaviour if an input string does not start with, but cotains, whitespace.